# Prove $\cos 3x =4\cos^3x-3\cos x$

Tags: trigonometry

How would I solve the following double angle identity.

$$\cos 3x =4\cos^3x-3\cos x $$

I know $\,\cos 3x  = \cos(2x+x)$

So know I have $\,\cos 2x +\cos x \,$ , Which is $\,(2\cos^2x-1)\cos x$

But I am not sure what to do next.

Comment: Note $\cos(a+b) \neq \cos(a) + \cos(b),$ and $\cos(a+b) =  \cos(a) \cos(b) - \sin(a) \sin(b).$

Comment: I think triple angle identity would fit better, no?

Comment: Oh I see now so it would (cos2x)cosx-sin2x(sinx) I think I understand how to solve the problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is a _triple_-angle identity, not a _double_-angle identity.  And one may _solve_ equations or _prove_ identities, but to speak of "solving" an identity is somewhat confused.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

$$e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x\Rightarrow e^{3ix}=(\cos x+i\sin x)^3\Rightarrow\cos 3x+i\sin 3x=(\cos x+i\sin x)^3$$

Now expand the cube and equate the real and imaginary parts of both sides to get the answer.

Comment: +1 Beautiful, though it might be over the OP's level...

Comment: But that's the real proof. And by the same proof you get formulas for $\cos(nx)$, $\sin(nx)$ for any integers $n \ge 2$. And furthermore you can copy the formulas right off of Pascal's triangle.

Comment: @LeeMosher - why is this not a real proof ? looks OK to me

Answer (score 14):

\begin{eqnarray}
\cos(3x) &=& \cos(2x+x)\\
&=& \cos(2x)\cos x - \sin(2x)\sin x\\
&=& (\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x)\cos x - 2\sin^2 x\cos x\\
&=& \cos^3 x -(1-\cos^2 x)\cos x - 2 (1 -\cos^2 x)\cos x\\
&=& 2 \cos^3 x -\cos x + \cos^3 x -2 \cos x\\
&=& 4 \cos^3 x - 3 \cos x
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 5):

I might as well: there is in fact a useful recurrence (Chebyshev) that you can use for expressing $\cos\,nx$ entirely in terms of powers of $\cos\,x$:

$$\cos((n+1)x)=2\cos(x)\cos(nx)-\cos((n-1)x)$$

In this case, you can start with $\cos\,x$ and $\cos\,2x=2\cos^2 x-1$:

$$\begin{align*}
\cos\,3x&=(2\cos\,x)(2\cos^2 x-1)-\cos\,x\\
&=4\cos^3 x-2\cos\,x-\cos\,x=4\cos^3 x-3\cos\,x
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 4):

I will attempt to answer my own question now.

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\cos(2x)(\cos x)-\sin(2x)(\sin x)& =& (2\cos^2 x-1)(\cos x)-2\sin x\cdot\cos x\cdot\sin x\\
&=&2\cos^3x-\cos x-2\sin^2 x\cos x\\
&=&2\cos^3x-\cos x-2(1-\cos^2 x)(\cos x)\\
&=&2\cos^3x-\cos x-2\cos x+2\cos^3 x\\
&=&4\cos^3 x-3\cos x
\end{eqnarray}$$

Answer (score 0):

In general, a product of sin and cos functions can be easily solved via Fourier series expansion and convolution.