# Solving Trigonometric Equations

Tags: trigonometry

Solve $x$ in the equation $2\cos3x + \cos2x + 1= 0$, where $0 \leq x \leq 2\pi$.

I tried breaking up the triple angle, into a cos compound angle. But, im not sure what to do next.

$2\cos x \cos2x - 2\sin x \sin2x + \cos2x+1=0$

Comment: If you keep going you can obtain a cubic in $\cos(x)$. Specifically, use $\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$ and $\cos(2x) = 2\cos^2(x)-1$

Answer (score 1):

Using [Prove $\cos 3x =4\cos^3x-3\cos x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175903/prove-cos-3x-4-cos3x-3-cos-x) and Double-Angle Formula, we get $$2(4c^3-3c)+2c^2-1+1=0\iff2c(4c^2+c-3)=0$$ where $c=\cos x$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: @user146001, How about this?