# Proving the trigonometrical identities

Tags: trigonometry

please prove this answer, step by step..
$$\cos A - \cos 3A = 4 \sin^2A \cos A$$
I had just finished the left side $= -2 \sin 2A \sin A$
but then I have no idea to prove it..

Answer (score 2):

We use the identity
$$\cos p-\cos q=-2\sin\left(\frac{p+q}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{p-q}{2}\right)$$
so with the double angle identity we have
$$\cos A-\cos3A=\color{red}+2\sin(2A)\sin A=2\times 2\sin A\cos A\times \sin A=4\sin^2 A\cos A$$

Comment: sorry.. but I don't understand why cos A - cos 3A can be + 2 sin (2A) sin A?

Comment: Apply the identity with $p=A$ and $q=3A$ you get
$$-2\sin(2A)\sin(-A)=2\sin(2A)\sin A$$

Comment: but sorry, why the identity is -2 sin and when it was applied to that problem it became +2?

Comment: As I explained because there are two negative signs: the negative sign of the identity and the negative sign from $\sin(-A)=-\sin A$.

Comment: ooo.. okay okay I understand.. thanks a lot ya!

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos(A)-\cos(3A)=\cos(A)-(\cos(2A)\cos(A)-\sin(2A)\sin(A))$$

$$=\underbrace{\cos(A)-\cos^{3}(A)}_{=\cos(A)(1-\cos^{2}(A))}+\cos(A)\sin^{2}(A)+2\sin^{2}(A)\cos(A)$$

$$=\cos(A)\sin^{2}(A)+3\sin^{2}(A)\cos(A)=4\sin^{2}(A)\cos(A)$$

Comment: sorry, but how can you get cos^3 there in the second line?

Comment: $\cos(2A)\cos(A)=(\cos^{2}(A)-\sin^{2}(A))\cos(A)=\cos^{3}(A)-\sin^{2}(A)\cos(A)$

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos3A=4\cos^3A-3\cos A\implies\cos A-\cos3A=4\cos A(1-\cos^2A)$$

Comment: sorry, from where you get 4 cos ^3 - 3cos A?

Comment: @user163618, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175903/prove-cos-3x-4-cos3x-3-cos-x

Answer (score 0):

(for $A \in \mathbb{R})$
$$
\cos A - \cos 3A = \mathfrak{Re} (e^{iA} - e^{3iA}) \\ =  \mathfrak{Re} \left(-2ie^{2iA}\frac{(e^{iA}-e^{-iA})}{2i}  \right) \\ = \mathfrak{Im} \left(2e^{2iA} \right) \sin A \\ =2 \sin 2A \sin A \\ =4 \sin^2A \cos A
$$

Comment: thanks but i don't understand those symbols.. but it's okay!